# Automatically create predefined objects in database for ManyToMany?

Tags: python, django, django-models

how would I go about automatically generating a list of objects in the database for DJango?

Example model:

```
#models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    BOOKS = (
        ('0','Secret Life of Bees'),
        ('1','Pride and Prejudice')
        )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=BOOKS)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Library(models.Model):
    librarian = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

How would I automatically add all the books to the database so I don't have to manually add them using the admin control panel?

Comment: Use a *data* migration, not `choices`, these do not add records, these simply restrict what `names` can be used.

Comment: @Nick, Do you want to set default values for M2M field?

Comment: @NKSM Yes, I want all the values for Books to be predefined.

Comment: @NKSM This is useful information, and good to note, but not quite what I am asking. To be explicit, how would I automatically create each individual book object (Secret Life of Bees, Pride and Prejudice) without adding them in the admin interface manually?

Answer (score 0):

Update! To anyone who doesn't know how to do this, you can call `Object.objects.bulk_create(Object([Object(property=propertyInfo),Object(property=propertyInfo)]).`